Could not determine the dependencies of null
I'm using the react native cli to create an Android mobile app. I'm attempting to execute on an android studio emulator. Whenever I run npx react-native run-android in the terminal, I receive an error.
PS C:\Users\Administrator\highMobileProgramming\MoneyBook> npx react-native run-android
(node:13480) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
   > The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of null. > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'. > The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 2s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

I've already used react native doctor, and it says there are no issues or warnings.
enter image description here
when I asked chat gpt, it told me to install java 21 so I also tried that.
enter image description here
and ./gradlew clean isnt working to me.
PS C:\Users\Administrator\highMobileProgramming\MoneyBook\android> ./gradlew clean

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
   > The new Java toolchain feature cannot be used at the project level in combination with source and/or target compatibility

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

this is my build.gradle file.
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 35
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }


}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 35
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
    }

    // sourceCompatibility 및 targetCompatibility 추가
    compileOptions {
        //sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
        //targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    }

    // toolchain
    java {
         toolchain {
             languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
         }
    }
}

//plugins {
//    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false // firebase google-service
//}
//
//apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"`

and this is my gradle-wrapper.properties file
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
I realize it's long. If you leave a comment, it will much help me... I've been working on this for three days and can't seem to find a solution.
react native cli working normally without error
